# If my app created a Android Content Provider, will the provider disappear if my app gets uninstalled?

Tags: android

I want to store some data in the content provider, so some of my other apps will be able to access the info as well. But my question is if the app I use to write the content provider gets uninstalled, does it mean that the content provider is gone as well? If so, is there anyway to prevent that, or is there alternative place I can store date to share across multiple apps? And one more question, is there something similar to pasteboard in iOS for android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a round search and testings, I have found the answer myself.

Well, it depends. There are 2 ways of using/changing Content Provider

1. To make changes the default content provider, such as contacts. If your app added an entry of contact, the contact is still there even the app gets deleted
2. To make your own content provider. But this gets removed when the app gets uninstalled.

Answer (score 4):

> But my question is if the app I use to write the content provider gets uninstalled, does it mean that the content provider is gone as well?

By definition, if you remove the content provider, the content provider is removed.

> If so, is there anyway to prevent that

No. Users are free to uninstall whatever they like that they installed.

> is there alternative place I can store date to share across multiple apps?

External storage, or the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response!Is external storage physically safe? What if the external storage is a n SD card, does it mean that if the user take the SD card, everything will be gone? Is there anyway I can determine the place I put my data is a non-removable storage? Thanks!

Comment: @sammiwei: "if the user take the SD card, everything will be gone?" -- of course. "Is there anyway I can determine the place I put my data is a non-removable storage?" -- no. You cannot assume that external storage will always be available, particularly on Android 1.x and 2.x. External storage may be physically present but unavailable to you because it has been mounted as a drive on the user's desktop or notebook.

Comment: @CommonsWave I do not know if you are familiar with the pasteboard in iOS, but do you know beside internal and external data storage, where else can I keep the data?

Comment: @sammiwei: Your three choices are internal storage, external storage, and the Internet, as I outlined in the answer.